# find all offsets of pcre2 matches

Tags: c, pcre2

I want to write a function `int** text_match(const char* input, const char* pattern);` that returns all match offsets(start and end respectively)

So far I have implemented this, by iterating over the input with an input offset, finding out if there is a match within the input + its offset, obtaining the offset and setting the input offset to the end offset of the match.

This approach has some very significant disadvantages

- some patterns exists that can cause an infinite amount of matches (^|\n|$)
- even once these infinite execution issues are fixed with (^|\n) will always find a match at the beginning of the string-fragment, thus viewing every index as a match

I experimented with `pcre2_get_ovector_count()` a bit, however so far whenever I provide it with the `pcre2_match_data`after having run `pcre2_match()` it only returns 1 and not the actual amount of matches

How could I find out all match offsets with pcre2 directly? Or at least avoid the issues I have described above?

*my implementation so far* (will be licensed under the MIT)

```c
int** text_match(const char* input, const char* regex){
    if(!input || !regex) return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));

    int errorcode;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroroffset;

    pcre2_code *compiled_regex = pcre2_compile((PCRE2_SPTR)regex, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, PCRE2_EXTENDED|PCRE2_UTF, &errorcode, &erroroffset, NULL);

    if(!compiled_regex) return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    
    pcre2_match_data *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(compiled_regex, NULL);
    
    if(!match_data){
        pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);

        return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    }

    int** output = (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    if(!output){
        pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);
        pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);

        return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    }
    
    PCRE2_SIZE start_offset = 0;

    int matches_amount;
    
    size_t length_input = strlen(input);

    for(matches_amount = 0; ; matches_amount++){
        if(start_offset >= length_input) break;
    
        if(pcre2_match(compiled_regex, (PCRE2_SPTR)input, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, start_offset, 0, match_data, NULL) < 0) break;
        
        PCRE2_SIZE *offsets = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);
        
        if(offsets == NULL) break;

        output[matches_amount] = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        
        if(output[matches_amount] == NULL) break;

        output[matches_amount][0] = offsets[0];
        output[matches_amount][1] = offsets[1];

        int** new_output = (int**)realloc(output, sizeof(int*) * (matches_amount + 2));
        if(new_output == NULL) break;
        output = new_output;

        if(start_offset == offsets[1]){
            start_offset++;
        }else{
            start_offset = offsets[1];
        }
    }
    
    output[matches_amount] = NULL;
    
    pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);
    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);

    return output;
}
```

## Edit:

As pointed out by @ikegami the approach was right, however I did too little edge-case detection. This edit just serves one purpose. To provide the corrected function so that if someone finds this post at a later time and needs a function for this here you have it(will be licensed under the MIT btw so do with it whatever you want)

```c
int** text_match(const char* input, const char* regex){
    if(!input || !regex) return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));

    int errorcode;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroroffset;

    pcre2_code *compiled_regex = pcre2_compile((PCRE2_SPTR)regex, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, PCRE2_EXTENDED|PCRE2_UTF, &errorcode, &erroroffset, NULL);

    if(!compiled_regex) return (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    
    pcre2_match_data *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(compiled_regex, NULL);
    
    if(!match_data){
        pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);

        return NULL;
    }

    int** output = (int**)calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
    if(!output){
        pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);
        pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);

        return NULL;
    }
    
    PCRE2_SIZE start_offset = 0;

    int matches_amount;
    
    size_t length_input = strlen(input);

    uint32_t options = 0;

    for(matches_amount = 0; ; matches_amount++){
        if(pcre2_match(compiled_regex, (PCRE2_SPTR)input, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, start_offset, options, match_data, NULL) < 0) break;
        
        PCRE2_SIZE *offsets = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);
        
        if(offsets == NULL) break;

        output[matches_amount] = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
        
        if(!output[matches_amount]){
            for(int i = 0; output[i]; i++) free(output[i]);
            free(output);
            pcre2_code_free_8(compiled_regex);
            pcre2_match_data_free_8(match_data);
            
            return NULL;
        }

        output[matches_amount][0] = offsets[0];
        output[matches_amount][1] = offsets[1];

        int** new_output = (int**)realloc(output, sizeof(int*) * (matches_amount + 2));
        if(!new_output){
            for(int i = 0; output[i]; i++) free(output[i]);
            free(output);
            pcre2_code_free_8(compiled_regex);
            pcre2_match_data_free_8(match_data);
            
            return NULL;
        }
        output = new_output;
        
        if(offsets[0] == offsets[1]){
            if(offsets[0] == length_input) break;
            options = PCRE2_NOTEMPTY_ATSTART | PCRE2_ANCHORED;
        }else{
            size_t startchar = pcre2_get_startchar(match_data);
            if(start_offset > startchar) continue;
            start_offset = startchar + 1;
            
            for(; start_offset < length_input; start_offset++){
                if((input[start_offset] & 0xc0) != 0x80) break;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    output[matches_amount] = NULL;
    
    pcre2_code_free(compiled_regex);
    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: if you want to see proof of the issue just remove 
```
if(start_offset == offsets[1]){
            start_offset++;
        }else{
            start_offset = offsets[1];
        }
```

the issue lies with the fact that pcre2 will always detect a match at position 0 for(^|\n) and strlen(input) for $ 

It will loop over until it has eaten up all the memory on your poor PC

The issue does not inherently lie with pcre2 in that regard, they are reporting the output correctly, the issue arises once you try detect match offsets iteratively

something seems off the ovector_count

Comment: yeah, I just realized you meant *your code* finds an infinite number of matches.  Could you clarify what matches you expect from `a+` matched again `aaa`? Using start,length notation, do you expect the 6 matches 0,1; 0,2; 0;3, 1,1; 1,2; 2,1? Or just 3?

Comment: So far as I described in the post I tried the following for the ovector count

pcre2_get_ovector_count(match_data); just after pcre2_match() the output of pcre2_get_ovector_count() was somehow always one though

Comment: I expect the following output
0, 1;
1, 2;
2, 3;

(I do not intend to cover overlapping matches in the function and I don't know if the pcre2 ovector supports them)

Comment: unlike for pcre2_substitute there does not seem to be a PCRE2_..._GLOBAL flag for pcre2_match so that cannot be the cause of the issue  as well

Comment: I just don't follow the logic behind expecting 0, 1; 1, 2; 2, 3; as the result in that example.    If you match regex `a+` against string `aaa` then it will match *the whole string*.  It's unclear why it matters that the pattern would also match (the whole of) various substrings of the input string.  Or if you care about that, as you seem to do, then it's unclear why you care only about certain specific substrings and not others.  I suggest you spend some effort on writing a clear description of what you are trying to compute, *in words*.

Comment: In any event, `pcre2_get_ovector_count()` will return a value greater than 1 only when the pattern contains one or more capturing groups.  The additional ovectors describe the captured groups.  Overall, the match data reports on the match that was actually performed, not on alternative matches that *could have been* performed.

Comment: @JohnBollinger so is there a general way of obtaining all matches? and if not how can I avoid (^|\n) resulting in every index being matched rather than only the actual beginning?

Comment: @John Bollinger Re "*If you match regex `a+` against string `aaa` then it will match* the whole string.", I meant `a+?`, and the OP apparently replied as if I said `a+?`

Comment: I've done this before. Will try to dig up the code later today.

Comment: That's odd, @ikegami, because the alternatives you presented in your question are not all consistent with the pattern being `a+?`.  How would 0,3 be among the results with a reluctant quantifier?  Anyway, I'm sure the OP cannot read your mind any more than I can, so I remain uncertain whether they misinterpreted the pattern actually presented or whether they are applying some logic that eludes me.

Comment: @John Bollinger, Re "*How would 0,3 be among the results with a reluctant quantifier?*",  `perl -Mv5.14 -e'"aaa" =~ /a+?(?{ say $-[0], ",", $+[0]-$-[0] })(*FAIL)/;'` prints `0,1; 0,2; 0,3; 1,1; 1,2; 2,1` (LF swapped for `;`.)

Comment: @John Bollinger, ...oh right, you get the same for `a+` without the `?`. Just in a different order. `0,3; 0,2; 0,1; 1,2; 1,1; 2,1`. Anyway, I was asking if they wanted all possible matches including overlapping matches, or just the different matches as if /g was used. And that was answered (different matches as if /g was used).

Comment: (To be clear, it was answered as follows: "I do not intend to cover overlapping matches in the function")

Comment: You might want to look at the [pcre2demo source](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/blob/master/src/pcre2demo.c), it has an example of how to emulate Perl's `/g` flag, finding all matches.

Comment: @Hasturkun, See my answer from 9 minutes ago :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`pcre2demo`](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2demo.html) man page provides a demo. It includes the following:

```c
/* Loop for second and subsequent matches */

for (;;)
  {
  uint32_t options = 0;                   /* Normally no options */
  PCRE2_SIZE start_offset = ovector[1];   /* Start at end of previous match */

  /* If the previous match was for an empty string, we are finished if we are
  at the end of the subject. Otherwise, arrange to run another match at the
  same point to see if a non-empty match can be found. */

  if (ovector[0] == ovector[1])
    {
    if (ovector[0] == subject_length) break;
    options = PCRE2_NOTEMPTY_ATSTART | PCRE2_ANCHORED;
    }

  /* If the previous match was not an empty string, there is one tricky case to
  consider. If a pattern contains \K within a lookbehind assertion at the
  start, the end of the matched string can be at the offset where the match
  started. Without special action, this leads to a loop that keeps on matching
  the same substring. We must detect this case and arrange to move the start on
  by one character. The pcre2_get_startchar() function returns the starting
  offset that was passed to pcre2_match(). */

  else
    {
    PCRE2_SIZE startchar = pcre2_get_startchar(match_data);
    if (start_offset <= startchar)
      {
      if (startchar >= subject_length) break;   /* Reached end of subject.   */
      start_offset = startchar + 1;             /* Advance by one character. */
      if (utf8)                                 /* If UTF-8, it may be more  */
        {                                       /*   than one code unit.     */
        for (; start_offset < subject_length; start_offset++)
          if ((subject[start_offset] & 0xc0) != 0x80) break;
        }
      }
    }

  ...
}
```

So you are indeed expected to manipulate the start position (and the options as well), although there are some issues with your current implementation.

Comment: what should be done if the start_offset > startchar ?

Comment: Nothing. `start_offset` should be used without modification. The very next line of the demo is the call to `pcre2_match`, which uses `start_offset` as the 4th argument.

Comment: Nothing. No correction is needed. `start_offset` should be used without modification. The very next line of the demo is the call to `pcre2_match`, which uses `start_offset` as the 4th argument.

Answer (score 0):

> So far I have implemented this, by iterating over the input with an input offset, finding out if there is a match within the input + its offset, obtaining the offset and setting the input offset to the end offset of the match.

From this I think I understand that you want to find non-overlapping matches to the pattern within the input string, working from beginning to end.

> This approach has some very significant disadvantages
>
> - some patterns exists that can cause an infinite amount of matches (^|\n|$)

You seem to be characterizing that as an implementation issue, but it is a *design* issue, first.  What is **supposed** to happen with zero-length matches?  One possibility is that inputs that produce zero-length matches should be considered erroneous.  Another is that zero-length matches should be ignored.  Another is that they should be reported once each.  Any of these can be implemented, but you need to decide.

> - even once these infinite execution issues are fixed with (^|\n) will always find a match at the beginning of the string-fragment, thus
>   viewing every index as a match

That's again producing zero-length matches, so not really a different problem.
Note well that there's nothing *inherently* wrong with matching every character or matching a zero-length string before every character, individually. If you don't want to report zero-length matches then nothing's forcing you to do.  If you *do* want to report them then you have to accept that there will be inputs for which there are a lot of such matches.

> I experimented with `pcre2_get_ovector_count()` a bit, however so far whenever I provide it with the `pcre2_match_data` after having run `pcre2_match()` it only returns 1 and not the actual amount of matches

1 ***is*** the actual number of matches.  `pcre_match()` finds at most one per call.  The first ovector reports the whole match.  Other ovectors, if any, report on captured groups within the overall match.  There will not be any of these if the pattern does not contain any capturing groups, and when there are any, they don't serve what seems to be your purpose.

> How could I find out all match offsets with pcre2 directly? Or at least avoid the issues I have described above?

Your general approach seems sound:

1. start with the whole input, from offset 0
2. find a match starting from the current offset.

- quit if none is found<sup>*</sup>
- otherwise record the match<sup>*</sup>

3. update the offset to just after the end of the match<sup>*</sup>
4. Go back to (2)

But you do need to pay some attention at least to zero-length matches, according to whatever handling you decide you want to apply.  That might mean that in (2), you abort with an error on a zero-length match, or that you avoid recording zero-length matches.  If you do not abort on zero-length matches then presumably in (3), you will want to advance the offset by a minimum of 1 code unit, so that you don't get stuck finding the same match over and over.